# How to Submit and Display on the same page using jQuery and MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, submission

**Goal:**

Create a Q&A Script (using PHP, JavaScript and jQuery) that enables users to ask questions and submit answers to said questions.
If the user submitted a new answer, that answer would be inserted into the database and the div containing the answers would be refreshed automatically to include/view that newly submitted answer.

**Problem:**

After submitting the answer, the submission process is *not working*.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
      {
         /*Function # 4:
            Hide the AnswerForm and show  Answers where the div will be automatically refreshed upon answer submission.  <>>>> REVIEW!!! */
        function addAnswer(i,qID)
        {
            //alert("newanswer-q"+i);

            //$("newanswer-q"+i).style.display("none");
            //$("Answers-q"+i).style.display("block"); 
            changeDiv("Answers-q"+i, "block");

            //step # 1: define posted data to insert into database
            var name = $("input#name").val();;
            var answer = $("input#answer").val();;

             alert(name+","+answer);

             //step # 2: submit form to be processed by CHANGE.PHP to insert into DB
              $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"change.php",
              data: "questionID="+qID+"&count="+i+"&name="+name+"&answer="+answer,
              success: function(data)
                        {
                            if(data==0)
                            {
                                alert("YEEEEEEEEEESSSS!!!!!! :DDDDDD");
                                $("#Answer-q"+i).html("Finally!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#Answer-q"+i).html("?!?!");
                            }
                        }
              });

            //Step # 3: refresh Answers div
            //changeDiv('Answers-q'+i, 'block');  

            $("#Answers-q"+i).load("printAnswers.php"); 
        }//end addAnswer


        $("#refreshAnswers").click(function(evt){
        $("#refreshAnswers").load("printAnswers.php");
        evt.preventDefault();
        }); 
    }
    </script>


        <style type="text/css">

        .answers
        {
            background-color: red; 
            position: relative; 
            display: block; 
            left: 1in;
        }

        .answerform
        {
            background-color: yellow; 
            position: relative; 
            display: block; 
            left: 1in;
        }
        .error
        {
            color: red;
            display:none;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php   
            mysql_connect("#", "#", "#") or die(mysql_error()); 
            mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 

            $q1 = "SELECT * 
                   FROM questions";
            $allQ = mysql_query($q1);
            while($q = mysql_fetch_array($allQ)) 
            {
                $i = $q['qID'];

                echo '<div id="questions" style="background-color: blue;">';
                echo 'Question: '.$q['Question'].'<br><br>';
                echo 'posted by '.$q['userName'].'<br><br>';
                echo 'posted on '.$q['addDate'].'<br><br>';
                echo '</div>';?>

                <input type="button"  id="viewAnswers" name="viewAnswers" value="View Answers" onClick="changeDiv('Answers-q<?=$i?>', 'block');">
                <input type="button" id="addAnswer" name="addAnswer" value="Answer Question" onClick="changeDiv('newanswer-q<?=$i?>', 'block');">

                <div id="Answers-q<?=$i?>" class="answers">
                    <? include("printAnswers.php"); // display all answers to question # i
?>
                </div>

            <? echo '<div id="newanswer-q'.$i.'" class="answerform">'; 
                        include("addAnswerForm.php"); // display add new answer to question # i
               echo '</div>';
            } ?>
            <br>-------------------------<br>
            Go back to <a href="index.php">index.php</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Change.php

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('#', '#', '#') or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error()); 

    // Get values from form 
    $name=$_POST['name'];

    $answer=$_POST['answer'];

    $qID = $_POST['qID'];

    // Insert data into mysql 

    $sql="INSERT INTO answers(Answer, userName, qID)
          VALUES('$answer', '$name','$qID')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours now with no luck thanks to my beginner-level skills in both PHP and jQuery.

Can anyone throw me a lifeline or something?

Comment: At a glance...in this line `<? include("printAnswers.php"); // display all answers to question # i?>` you are commenting out the closing php bracket. You need to either remove the comment, or move the closing bracket down a line so it's not behind the comment.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of data? Try `console.log(data)` in your success function. Seems to me change.php doesn't produce any output, so why should data equal zero ?

Comment: That is to check if it is false or not. In any case, I fixed that problem only now I get the form input inserted into my database as many times as my while loop iterations with no qID data. (check below entry for my code so far...)

Answer (score 0):

Your data appears to be sent via "GET" request.

Change te AJAX data object to this:

```
data : {
  questionID : qid,
  count : i,
  name : name,
  answer : answer
}
```

If you pass it as a string the way you did, it gets appended to the URL (becoming a GET request), if you pass it as an object it gets posted.